Using AppThemeBinding to display different images in .NET MAUI
I want to display a different image depending on the system theme mode. I'm creating a simple money counter app where I use a CollectionView to display various fields in which the user type the quantity of a certain bill/coin, and it shows the total value. Each item also shows an image of the current bill/coin. I created two versions for each item, one for dark mode, one for light mode.
I'm using the following DataTemplate:
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateDinheiro" x:DataType="model:DinheiroModel">

    <Frame BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}}" 
           BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Background}, Dark={StaticResource PrimaryDark}}" 
           Margin="10, 5, 10, 5" Padding="10" HeightRequest="90">
        
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="2*, 3*, 1*" RowDefinitions="6*, 4*" ColumnSpacing="10">

            <Frame Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}}">
                <Image Scale="2.2">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <AppThemeBinding Light="{Binding CaminhoDoIconeLight}" Dark="{Binding CaminhoDoIconeDark}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Frame>

            <Frame BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Background}, Dark={StaticResource BackgroundDark}}" 
                   BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}}" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10, 0, 10, 0">
                
                <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" 
                       Text="{Binding Quantidade}" 
                       TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Text}, Dark={StaticResource TextDark}}" 
                       MaxLength="4"/>
            </Frame>
            
            <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Grid.Column="2" 
                    Command="{Binding DeletarCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ContagemViewModel}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    ImageSource="{AppThemeBinding Light=trashlight.png, Dark=trashdark.png}"
                    Scale="1.1"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding ValorTotal, StringFormat='R$ {0:#,0.#0}'}"
                   TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Text}, Dark={StaticResource TextDark}}"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                   FontFamily="InterMedium"
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        </Grid>   
    </Frame>
    
</DataTemplate>

This is the model it is binded to:
public partial class DinheiroModel : ObservableObject
{
    public double Valor { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(ValorTotal))]
    private int quantidade;

    public double ValorTotal => Valor * Quantidade;

    public string CaminhoDoIconeLight { get; set; }
    public string CaminhoDoIconeDark { get; set; }

    public DinheiroModel(double valor, string caminhoDoIconeLight, string caminhoDoIconeDark)
    {
        Valor = valor;
        quantidade = 0;
        CaminhoDoIconeLight = caminhoDoIconeLight;
        CaminhoDoIconeDark = caminhoDoIconeDark;
    }
}

In the ViewModel, each item is instantiated like this:
new DinheiroModel(0.05, "cinco_centavos_light.png", "cinco_centavos_dark.png")
However, the image is not displayed at all. What am I doing wrong?

The Light or Dark property of AppThemeBindingExtension is not bindable. So binding for them doesn't work.

What I noticed was the case in Xamarin Forms too was that AppThemeBinding did not work with ImageSource in XAML, do I know why? no!
The only solution I could come up with was to do this in the cs file and just so you know this does not break MVVM
  if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Light)
  {
      image.Source = "lightimage.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
      image.Source = "darkimage.png";
  }

Also if there is a chance that your application can change its theme on the screen that you are on you might want to subscribe to the Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged event

The Light and Dark property of AppThemeBindingExtension class is not a BindableProperty, so if you use Binding for it,
<AppThemeBinding Light="{Binding CaminhoDoIconeLight}" Dark="{Binding CaminhoDoIconeDark}"/>

it doesn't work. You may refer to AppThemeBindingExtension
I understand in the question you use a CollectionView/ListView and you may want to use bindings for that property. Instead of AppThemeBinding, you may try using Binding value converters.
Let's say you have one picture named dotnet_bot.png for light theme and dotnet_bot_dark.png for dark mode. Here is the Converter,
public class MyThemeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Light)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            var light = value as string;               
            var dark = light.Split(".")[0] + "_dark.png";
            return dark;               
        }
    }

This is how the xaml consumes the Binding Converter,
 <Frame Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}}">
            <Image Scale="2.2" Source="{Binding CaminhoDoIcone,Converter={StaticResource myThemeConverter}}">
                
            </Image>
        </Frame>


One solution is to use AppThemeBinding with a DataTrigger. You can hard-code a value, such as "D" for dark mode, and configure the DataTrigger setter(s) to apply your dark mode preferences. The Image will then be configured by default for light mode.
<Image Source="{Binding LightImage}">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{AppThemeBinding Dark=D}" TargetType="Image" Value="D">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DarkImage}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>

Alternatively, you can use AppThemeBinding with your DataTemplates. Since you’ve already defined your DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary, this approach works well. You’ll just need to split it into two templates—one for light mode and the other for dark mode.
<CollectionView ItemTemplate="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource lightTemplate}, Dark={StaticResource darkTemplate}}" ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}">
    <CollectionView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="lightTemplate" x:DataType="model:DinheiroModel">
                <Image Source="{Binding LightImage}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="darkTemplate" x:DataType="model:DinheiroModel">
                <Image Source="{Binding DarkImage}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </CollectionView.Resources>
</CollectionView>

Combining the two ideas, you can apply AppThemeBinding with a DataTrigger on the DataTemplate. You'll need to have two DataTemplates in your ResourceDictionary: one configured as the default for light mode, and the other applied for dark mode through the DataTrigger.
<CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lightTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainItems}">
    <CollectionView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="lightTemplate" x:DataType="model:DinheiroModel">
                <Image Source="{Binding LightImage}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="darkTemplate" x:DataType="model:DinheiroModel">
                <Image Source="{Binding DarkImage}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </CollectionView.Resources>
    <CollectionView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{AppThemeBinding Dark=D}" TargetType="CollectionView" Value="D">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource darkTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </CollectionView.Triggers>
</CollectionView>

